# REST approach for API with detail

Tags: rest

I am designing one API and for example let's consider following scenario.

In my business domain there are total three entity A, B and C.

A to B has one to many relation.
B to c has one to many relation.

There are multiple A record in application.

So If I design REST API then it will look like this.

```
GET /api/A  ( return list of A)
GET /api/A/{id} ( return specific record of A)
POST /api/A  ( new record)
PUT  /api/A/{id} ( update)

Get /api/A/{id}/B ( List of B record with A with specific Id as parent)
```

same for other endpoint and B to C follow same structure.

Now few questions.

1. When I get list of A , I want to apply complex filter criteria and somewhat it is not good to have as query or GET operation

   - Is it ok to use POST method ? Is this breaking REST rule ? If so How to handle case.
2. Also when List of A record display in UI , it also display count no of B and No of C inside that.

   - How we expose this data  ?

Can we expose POST with /api/A/search ( for complex search) ?

Also how to include other child property and still follow the REST ?

Comment: Too many questions. Please split it up in multiple posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I get list of A , I want to apply complex filter criteria and somewhat it is not good to have as query or GET operation

> Is it ok to use POST method ? Is this breaking REST rule ?

Will POST *work*?  Yes.

Is this breaking a rule?  Yes.

> It isn’t RESTful to use POST for information retrieval when that information corresponds to a potential resource, because that usage prevents safe reusability and the network-effect of having a URI. -- [Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> Can we expose POST with /api/A/search ( for complex search) ?

POST has the same problem as before.

But /api/A/search is fine - it is *normal* to have many different resources (documents) that include copies of information from the same domain entities, or that combine information from multiple domain entities.  Think "web pages"; we combine information from different entities into a single web page all the time.

> Also how to include other child property and still follow the REST ?

By understanding that a resource/document model is a different thing than a domain/entity model.

Comment: Yes. I do get your point about web page where we query multiple entity and combine them and represent as required by UI. Like in ViewModel concept in MVC pattern.  if I have to do with pure REST approach then needs to make multiple api call and then I get desire result and this is somewhat against the performance. Overall confusion is between approach and performance. Both will not fit in same.

Comment: Combining multiple entities into a single representation _is_ the pure REST approach.  See https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Thinking resource = entity is problem. Resource is much broader terms so yes. I am accepting your answer.